# How to rectify Bad box error with overfull hbox message

Tags: miktex

I am writing a paper for a journal. When I run the latex program ,I get the Bad box error. I have read numerous queries about this error since the last 2 days but have not understood how to rectify it. Please help me in doing something that removes these errors. I am new to latex. Please help

```
 line 112: I can't write on file `template.pdf'. \subsection: File `example.eps' already exists on the system.

line 96: Overfull \hbox (3.50853pt too wide) in paragraph

line 96: Overfull \hbox (2.14626pt too wide) in paragraph

line 107: Overfull \hbox (1.81401pt too wide) in paragraph

 line 107: Overfull \hbox (6.34181pt too wide) in paragraph

 Underfull \vbox (badness 4096) has occurred while \output is active []
```

Please find the program below. It is basically a template of journal where I have filled my information.I  have tried to make the below program as short as possible by deleting the not so useful information.

```
  % First comes an example EPS file -- just ignore it and
  % proceed on the \documentclass line
  % your LaTeX will extract the file if required 
  \begin{filecontents*}{example.eps}

  gsave  
  newpath
  20 20 moveto
  20 220 lineto
  220 220 lineto
  220 20 lineto 
  closepath
  2 setlinewidth
  gsave
 .4 setgray fill
  grestore 
  stroke 
 grestore
 \end{filecontents*}
  %
 \RequirePackage{fix-cm}
  %
 \documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}          % twocolumn
  %
 \smartqed  % flush right qed marks, e.g. at end of proof  
  %
 \usepackage{graphicx} 
  %
 % \usepackage{mathptmx}      % use Times fonts if available on your TeX 
 %
% insert here the call for the packages your document requires
 %\usepackage{latexsym}
  % etc.
  % 
    % please place your own definitions here and don't use \def but
% \newcommand{}{}
 %
% Insert the name of "your journal" with
% \journalname{myjournal} 
%
\begin{document}

\title{Rxyz method of solving abc problem and checking its results by hjk 
 technique aaaaaaaa dddd %\thanks{Grants or other notes
 %about the article that should go on the front page should be
 %placed here. General acknowledgments should be placed at the end of the 
article.}
 }


 %\titlerunning{Short form of title}        % if too long for running head

 \author{mno        \and 
       pqr %etc.
  }

  %\authorrunning{Short form of author list} % if too long for running head

  \institute{nbh \at
          Department of xyc, mkj college \\
          Tel.: 12345-67890\\
          \email{abc@gmail.com}           %  \\
      %  \emph{Present address:} of F. Author  %  if needed
       \and
       bnm \at
          Department of def mnb college\\
          \email{cgm@gmail.com}
   }

    \maketitle

  \begin{abstract} 
   In this paper, a mixed method is proposed for the reduced order modelling 
   of linear time invariant (LTI) systems. It combines the 
   % \PACS{PACS code1 \and PACS code2 \and more}
     % \subclass{MSC code1 \and MSC code2 \and more}
 \end{abstract}

 \section{Introduction}
  \label{intro}
  Your text comes here. Separate text sections with
 \section{Section title}
 \label{sec:1}
 Model order reduction is a concept borrowed from mathematics where it was 
 being used to reduce the order of a system of ordinary differential 
equations. In systems and control engineering, it is found that most of the   
real time systems are complex and difficult to analyse and understand. The 
need to find an equivalent lower order system which preserves  \\
In the recent years, the research in model order reduction has led to the 
development of large number of methods with an aim to find a technique which 
works for all types of LTI systems. \\
This paper proposes a new  method based on xyz algorithm and avb technique. 
 The denominator of the system is obtained by abc techniqu
 Text with citations \cite{RefB} and \cite{RefJ}.
\subsection{Subsection title}
\label{sec:2}
as required. Don't forget to give each section
and subsection a unique label (see Sect.~\ref{sec:1}).
\paragraph{Paragraph headings} Use paragraph headings as needed.
 % For two-column wide figures use
 \begin{figure*} 
 %  Use the relevant command to insert your figure file.
  % For example, with the graphicx package use
 \includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth]{example.eps}
  % figure caption is below the figure
  \caption{Please write your figure caption here}
 \label{fig:2}       % Give a unique label
\end{figure*} 
 %
% Non-BibTeX users please use
\begin{thebibliography}{}
%
% and use \bibitem to create references. Consult the Instructions
% for authors for reference list style.
%
 \bibitem{RefJ}
  % Format for Journal Reference
  Author, Article title, Journal, Volume, page numbers (year)
   % Format for books
    \bibitem{RefB}
    Author, Book title, page numbers. Publisher, place (year)
   % etc
    \end{thebibliography}
     \end{document}
      % end of file template.tex
```

Comment: Welcome, have you considered reading some introductory material?

Comment: you need to show some code `Overfull \hbox (3.50853pt too wide)` just means that something is 3.5pt wider than  the space it is in. Perhaps it is a word that can not hyphenate or perhaps you have `\includegraphics[width=100pt]{}` in a line that is only 96.5 pt wide, it is impossible to tell from the information given.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Don't use `\\\` for line breaks, leave an empty line instead.

Comment: Was using  \\ the reason for such errors ?

Comment: But these hbox  were not warnings. They were error preventing compiling of program

Comment: @Shivam The only error I get when running your document is a superfluous `}` after the title. The corresponding error message is `Too many }'s. }` but this is not what you show us in your question.

Comment: I saved this template file under different filename and removed the '//'. Now I am not getting error.

Comment: If I run the same content under the earlier template filename I get those errors

Comment: I have understood the reason for Badbox with overfull hbox.  Suppose I compile the original file and open it as pdf. Next I do some changes in latex program but my previously open pdf file was not closed. Now I compile latex again. This will give the above mentioned errors given in question. So what i understood is that the pdf file must be closed before compiling the program again